# JasmineJS/AngularJs: How to spyOn $filter

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-filter

Suppose we have a `service` function that uses a `filter`. How do we `spyOn` on that `filter` to make sure that it gets called?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
describe('myServiceTest', function() {
    var myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter;
    var myFilterSpy  = jasmine.createSpy('');

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('myFilterFilter', myFilterSpy );
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter_) {
        myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter = _myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter_;
    }));

});
```